# Java app to read HTTPS requests

Tags: java, android, ios, https

I'm trying to build a backend to an iOS app. I was wondering if there was any example on how to create the java backend to handle HTTPS requests? I want to keep in mind scalability...so obviously need to be able to add more servers to handle the requests in the future. Is there something already available to look at? Code samples perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most web containers written in Java support https, but how to configure it is individual.

If you just want to get started, Tomcat and Jetty are two well known web containers with good documentation (my personal preference is Jetty, but that is not founded in anything technical - both are good).

For Tomcat, see:  http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

For Jetty, see: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/How+to+configure+SSL

Note that you will need a certificate so the devices will trust you.  For now you can create your own self-signed certificat and teach your development device to trust that.

Comment: I don't understand... So say I have a website www.sample.com written in JSF. Say I wanted to create a mobile app for it, you're saying that into the site I would need to create pages for mobile and send JSON messages to it?

Comment: You asked about how to handle https in the java backend.  This is the responsibility of the container you have deployed your JSF-application to.  Note that https is a transport like http, your code essentially do not need to know which one was used.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty), specifically the [Secure Chat example](http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/xref/org/jboss/netty/example/securechat/package-summary.html).